# Is there any sorts of links in Cassandra DB cql?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I’m building an app using Cassandra as DB and I was wondering if there is any way to copy paste and « sync » a column value with another.
I’ve tried to use materialized views but I wasn’t able to add additional regular columns in the same row where the view was created. I also saw this diagram that is about « links » in cql.

[cql links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdJHI.jpg)

Can anyone help my finding a way of doing this please?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way to do that in Cassandra. You will need to use CQL `BATCH` statements to keep your tables synchronised. It will group inserts, updates and deletes into one atomic transaction. Have a look at this article where I've explained it in a bit more detail -- https://community.datastax.com/articles/2744/.

For example, if you had these tables to maintain:

- `movies`
- `movies_by_actor`
- `movies_by_genre`

then you would group the updates in a CQL `BATCH` like this:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO movies (...) VALUES (...);
  INSERT INTO movies_by_actor (...) VALUES (...);
  INSERT INTO movies_by_genre (...) VALUES (...);
APPLY BATCH;
```

Note that it is also possible to do `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements as well as conditional writes in a batch.

The above example is just to illustrate it in cqlsh and is not used in reality. Here is an example `BatchStatement` using the Java driver:

```
SimpleStatement insertMovies =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance(
    "INSERT INTO movies (...) VALUES (?, ...)", <some_values>);

SimpleStatement insertMoviesByActor =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance(
    "INSERT INTO movies_by_actor (...) VALUES (?, ...)", <some_values>);

SimpleStatement insertMoviesByGenre =
  SimpleStatement.newInstance(
    "INSERT INTO movies_by_genre (...) VALUES (?, ...)", <some_values>);

BatchStatement batch =
  BatchStatement.builder(DefaultBatchType.LOGGED)
    .addStatement(insertMovies)
    .addStatement(insertMoviesByActor)
    .addStatement(insertMoviesByGenre)
    .build();
```

For details, see [Java driver Batch statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/statements/batch/). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

But in my project, if we do updates each time a user changes his onformations we would, in an extreme case, update thousands of values in different keyspaces.
Could this cause performance issues or would it be ok ?

Thank you

Comment: What is "onformations"? And I don't understand why you would "update thousands of values"? Please elaborate. Perhaps you have modelled your data incorrectly but it's hard to know without knowing the details. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry i meant "informations". I would need to update thousands of values because,, for example, when a user creates a post I store his name and profile picture url in the post's row so, if he created a thousand posts, I would need to update his informations in one thousand rows at the same time.